# Haskell QuickCheck generating values within a function

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

How do I get this contrived example to work?

```
newtype Q = Q [Int]

instance Arbitrary Q where
    arbitrary :: Gen Q
    arbitrary = do
        len <- choose (1, 5)
        pure $ g len (\ i -> i + choose (0, 1)) -- want different choice for each invocation

g :: Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Q -- g is a library function
g len f = Q $ fmap f [1 .. len]
```

It gives compiler error:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Gen a0'
    * In the second argument of `(+)', namely `choose (0, 1)'
      In the expression: i + choose (0, 1)
      In the second argument of `g', namely `(\ i -> i + choose (0, 1))'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `choose (0, 1)` does not produce an `Int`, it produces a `Gen Int`.

You're treating it as though it were an `Int` in this expression:

```
pure $ g (\i -> i + choose (0, 1))
```

Since `Gen Int` is a monad you need to bind it in order to use the result of the "choice".

Something like this:

```
instance Arbitrary Q where
    arbitrary :: Gen Q
    arbitrary = do
        choice <- choose (0, 1)
        return $ g (\i -> i + choice)
```

**Responding to the edited question:**

The issue is still the same, you're trying to use the `Gen Int` as though it were an `Int`.
You can bind multiple times inside a `do`.

Here is a solution:

```
instance Arbitrary Q where
    arbitrary :: Gen Q
    arbitrary = do
        len <- choose (1, 5)
        choice <- choose (0, 1)
        return $ g len (\i -> i + choice)
```

**Responding to the edited, edited question**:

You have to propagate the side effects somewhere, this just means you need to run `choose` `len` times. Because `g` is a "library" function, I'm going to assume that you have no control over it, and can't change it. Note that the solution below is ugly since I need to use the partial function `(!!)`, and because it is rather slow (there is probably a better way to do this, but I'm not able to find it).

The trick here is I'm mapping a function that returns `len` `Gen Int`'s, and then runs all of them, producing a list of chosen numbers (see [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:mapM) description for more details).

```
instance Arbitrary Q where
 arbitrary :: Gen Q
 arbitrary = do
     len <- choose (1, 5)
     choices <- mapM (\_ -> choose (0, 1)) [1 .. len]
     return $ g len (\i -> i + (choices !! i))
```

Comment: Please direct your answer towards my edited example . (sorry for the late edit)

Comment: @LoHaBuyshan2 , the answer is very similar. Updated.

Comment: But you are passing in a constant for `choice`. I want a different choice for each invocation. (I just added that as a comment in the example code)